# Prove that $\forall x: \sin^2{x} \leq |\sin{x}|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification

This seems deceptively simple to me but I need to prove that
$$\forall x: \, \sin^2{x} \leq |\sin{x}|$$
. This is for a "transition to advanced math" book that I am self-studying, so up to this point the book has covered simple proof techniques and absolute values.

- Case 1 ($\sin{x} \geq 0$): Since $x$ is nonnegative, $|\sin{x}| = \sin{x}$. By definition, we know that $0 \leq \sin{x} \leq 1$. Multiply both sides by $\sin{x}$ and we have $0 \leq \sin^2{x} \leq \sin{x} = |\sin{x}|$.
- Case 2 ($\sin{x} \lt 0$): Since $x$ is negative, $|\sin{x}| = -\sin{x}$. We also know that $-1 \leq \sin{x} \leq 0$. Again, multiply by $\sin{x}$ and we have $-\sin{x} \geq \sin^2{x} \geq 0$. After rearranging the terms, we have again shown that $\sin^2{x} \leq -\sin{x} = |\sin{x}|$ $\qquad \qquad \square$

Comment: $\sin(x)$ could be negative for positive $x $ and vice versa

Comment: Did you mean to use $\sin x \geq 0$ and $\sin x < 0$ as your two cases?

Comment: The general approach of using the bounds on the sine function is good. These bounds say that $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$. Try just working with this one inequality (you won't need cases).

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes you are of course right. I went through this mindlessly.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, I did mean for that. Thanks for pointing out my error.

Comment: @Dave If I'm following, I would multiply both sides by $|\sin{x}|$, and since $|\sin{x}|^2 = \sin^2{x}$, the result follows immediately?

Comment: @ChrisWatson sounds good to me. I see that this is the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply using $t^2 = |t|^2$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|\sin x| \leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ gives:
\begin{align}
\sin^2x = |\sin x|\times|\sin x| \leq |\sin x| \times 1 = |\sin x|.
\end{align}

Comment: That's very simple and clear. I had been doing several simple proofs by cases that I hadn't even thought of your approach.